# ngRx, Rxjs Observable subscribe issue with firebase

Tags: angular, reactjs, rxjs, ngrx

In my redux store reducer I am changing state variables as usually do, and have subscribed state in one of my Angular 2 Component using rxjs Observable. the main issue is I am not getting the subscribe second time when I changed some property from backend (i-e State object property is changed).. please help me to resolve this issue.

**Observable Subscribed**

```
@select(['group', 'groups']) groups$: Observable<any>;
this.groups$.subscribe(group => {
        console.log('fired once', group);
    })
```

Comment: Is this correctly tagged? `@select` looks like `ng2-redux`, not `ngrx`.

Comment: yes I found my solution.. the issue was from the backend